# Comment traduire « associate's degree » en français ?

Tags: traduction, terminologie, curriculum-vitae

J'ai trouvé « association de la science » mais je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit correct.
Quelle serait l'expression communément utilisée en français ?

Le contexte est le suivant :

> Après avoir fini mon AS j'ai été accepté dans le niveau bac.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_degree) ne traduit pas le mot en français.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Les diplômes n'ont guère de sens qu'en connaissant le système qui les a délivrés (et parfois l'établissement exact).  Dans un cadre informel je dirais simplement BAC+ le nombre minimal d'années d'étude qui permettent d'obtenir le diplôme.  Dans un contexte plus formel, le titre exact dans la langue d'origine suivi de la même mention entre parenthèses.

Et je conseillerais la même chose pour les diplômes ayant un intitulé en français mais obtenu hors de France.

Arriver à citer un cursus français équivalent va demander une connaissance plus profonde et du système originel, et du système français. Sinon, le risque est de mal représenter la formation obtenue.  Ce risque dans la recherche d'emploi par exemple va se concrétiser par des offres ne correspondant pas aux compétences (ce qui est est un moindre mal sauf pour le moral quand d'autres candidats sont préférés par la suite parce qu'on ne répond pas aux attentes), et par l'absence d'offres correspondant aux compétences (ce qui est un gros problème).

Answer (score 6):

Le diplôme en question, délivré aux Etats-Unis, n'a pas d'appelation francophone spécifique à ma connaissance. (a priori [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_degree) semble confirmer)

En fait, le problème est le même que pour les *master degree* ou *bachelor degree*. Si l'on n'a pas besoin d'être très précis et formel (discussion courante avec un ami ou une relation), on pourra dire **l'équivalent d'un X** (X pouvant être dans le cas de la question posée ici plutôt DEUG ou BTS) et ce sera relativement clair pour l'interlocuteur francophone.

Dans un cadre plus formel, on pourra difficilement forcer la traduction sur une base littérale à cause du risque d'introduire des confusions, donc on pourrait faire le choix de ne pas traduire, mais d'inclure l'expression comme tout autre emprunt à une autre langue (que ce soit en utilisant des guillemets autour de l'expression ou bien par l'utilisation d'un style italique par exemple).

Le résultat de ces remarques sur la phrase proposée, dans le contexte d'une lettre de motivation ou de candidature (contexte que j'ai supposé à partir du contexte de la question, corrigez-moi si ce n'est pas le cas) :

> Après avoir fini mon « Associate [of Science] Degree » (équivalent BTS, bac+2), j'ai été accepté au niveau bac.

Comment: "équivalent DEUG/BTS" C'est basé sur autre chose que la durée des études?  Parce que pour moi associer les deux me semble indiquer qu'on a pas connaissance de quoi c'est équivalent. (À ma connaissance les programmes étaient tels que le premier conduisait principalement vers la poursuite des études, le second principalement directement vers la vie active).

Comment: Oui, ce n'est que pour donner un ordre d'idées. Les contenus et les modalités d'enseignement ne sont pas du tout équivalentes, ce n'est que pour donner une idée du temps impliqué dans la préparation de ces diplômes. Raison pour laquelle on choisira de s'en tenir à l'appelation originale anglophone quand on a besoin d'être plus précis.

Comment: @Romain: Dans ce cas autant s'en tenir à *BAC+2*.

Comment: Oui, c'est bien aussi. En revanche, pour y répondre, il nous faudrait connaître un peu plus le contexte d'utilisation. A qui s'adresse-t-on ici ? Et je voulais éviter de dire *Après avoir fini mon bac+2, j'ai été accepté au niveau bac* ...

Comment: Btw, DEUG ça n'existe plus à ma connaissance, je ne vois pas l’intérêt d'utiliser un terme obsolète.

Comment: @Romain: oui “bac” est une erreur ici, ça se voulait indiquer “bachelor” je suppose. Manque de bol c'est un autre quiproquo.

Comment: Bien vu, j'ai édité. Je ne te remercie pas de me rappeler à quel point mon passage en fac est aujourd'hui lointain. :-)

Comment: Soit dit en passant, même quand ca existait, DEUG ou BTS ne voulaient rien dire en Belgique notamment, où l'on parlait de graduat, régendat, licence, candidature, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's roughly equivalent to a DEUG, which is one year less than a license, which is a bit less than a bachelor's :-)..  Anyway, while technically DEUGs don't exist any more, everyone in France knows what they are, as long as you pronounce it roughly like 'dog' and don't try to spell it out.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipl%C3%B4me_d%27%C3%A9tudes_universitaires_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rales)